# How to uninstall Open Office from Linux

Tags: linux, openoffice

I am working on Fedora 10,
I want to uninstall all the Open Office packages from my Linux system.
I need to install another version (*OOo_3.1.1_LinuxIntel_install_en-US.tar.gz*).

Answer (score 3):

The yum command works great for me:

```
yum remove openoffice*
```

Please note the last `*` after openoffice.  I first used `yum remove openoffice` and it did not work, then I realized the missing `*`.

By the way, I am using Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.1, which is binary compatible with RHEL 6.1.

Comment: worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do:

```
rpm -qa | egrep "^ooo|openoffice" | xargs sudo rpm -e
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no technical need to uninstall the installed office packages, they can coexist. But if you want to, you can find & deinstall them using Fedora's package manager.

OOo_3.1.1_LinuxIntel_install_en-US.tar.gz can be installed by just unpacking it to an arbitrary directory, then installing the RPMs inside (using e.g. rpm).

Comment: which will probably lead to conflicts... usually, installing a non-package distribution of an application does not interfere with a packages one, but if packages have same names in this distribution, it will conflict. Also, an unexperienced user might not realize which version is actually used (depending on which binary is in the path and how he starts)

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove it using Yum directly in Terminal

> yum remove openoffice*

I don't have access to my linux box at the moment so I can't remember if it is open-office or openoffice.

Comment: Does this work if the installation wasn't done using yum?  I have this problem because it seems as though my installation is corrupt but I installed it using the installer from the OO website not through yum...

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
rpm -e openffice*
```

Otherwise you can go to *Application → Add/Remove Software* and search for OpenOffice. This will be a safe method.

Answer (score 0):

I am an Ubuntu user and I had to remove both the basic packages and the core packages of Open Office. In order to do so, I ran the below command:

`sudo apt-get purge openoffice*.* && sudo apt-get purge openoffice-*.*`

Similarly, if it is run using `yum` i.e. the fedora package manager, it should work.